# What's the difference between indexed type and function signatures of TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have question about difference between indexed type and function signatures of TypeScript.

```js
type A = {
  _(num: number): void;
}['_'];

type B = {
  _(ten: 10): void;
}['_'];
let a: A = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
};

let b: B = (ten) => {
  console.log(ten);
};

a = b;
b = a;
```

In the code above, there is no error, but in the following code:

```js
type A = (num: number) => void;

type B = (ten: 10) => void;

let a: A = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
};

let b: B = (ten) => {
  console.log(ten);
};

a = b;  // ❌
b = a;
```

I get the error:

```
Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  Types of parameters 'ten' and 'num' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '10'.ts(2322)
```

What could be the difference between them?
Why does the first code not throw an error?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes "the setting only applies to functions written in function syntax, not to those in method syntax"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error comes from [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), that the sub-typing relationship goes backwards for function inputs.

---

"Plastic bottle" is a subtype of "garbage". What is the sub-typing relationship between bins that only takes plastic bottles and bins that can take any garbage?

"General garbage bin" is a subtype of "plastic bottle bin".
If you put a plastic bottle bin when people expect a general garbage bin, people are gonna throw other garbage that the plastic bottle bin can't take.

[`10`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) is a subtype of `number`, so `(num: number) => void` is a subtype of `(ten: 10) => void`

That's why in your second example `b = a` compiles fine but `a = b` doesn't, because `B` is not a subtype of `A`. This behaviour was [added in 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-6/), and is turned on with the flag `--strictFunctionTypes`. If you turn off this flag, both your examples should compile.

---

So why does the first example compiles when you get the function types from [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)?

[The documentation for this flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) says:

> During development of this feature, we discovered a large number of inherently unsafe class hierarchies, including some in the DOM. Because of this, the setting only applies to functions written in function syntax, not to those in method syntax

We can, however, change the *method* into a property that has a *function type*.

```
type A = {
  _: (num: number) => void;
}['_'];

type B = {
  _: (ten: 10) => void;
}['_'];
```

Then `a = b` fails to compile just like your second example.

Comment: I found the appropriate solution thanks to you.
If you do it like below, you can catch errors as intended even when using the "indexed access" method.

```ts
type A = {
  _: (num: number) => void;
}['_'];

type B = {
  _: (ten: 10) => void;
}['_'];
let a: A = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
};

let b: B = (ten) => {
  console.log(ten);
};

a = b; // ✅ can throw error
b = a;
```

Comment: Multi-line code is hard to read in comments, I have added that to my answer,